# Python: import _io

Tags: python, embed, portability

I'm trying to determine which files in the Python library are strictly necessary for my script to run. Right now I'm trying to determine where _io.py is located. In io.py (no underscore), the _io.py module (with underscore) is imported on line 60.

Comment: which version of Python? What are you trying to achieve exactly - it's unclear from the question

Comment: @Eli Bendersky I'm trying to make a portable app, and I'd like to find which libraries are needed by it. I'm running Python 3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some modules are compiled directly into the interpreter -- there are no files corresponding to them.  You can retrieve a list of these modules from [`sys.builtin_module_names`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).  In my Pyton 3.1 installation, `_io` is included in this list.

You might want to have a look at [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) to determine the dependencies of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Python modules are written in Python. Try looking for `_io.so` or `_io.pyd`.

Comment: A Windows search in the Python directory for files containing "_io" in the name returned only `/Lib/test/test_io.py` and `/Lib/test/test_ioctl.py`. Btw, I'm using Python 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

From python-list email archive: [*is "_io.py" missing from 2.7.4 ?*](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-April/644806.html), the situation for Python 2 and 3 is different:

#### In Python 2.7:

> To find where the `_io` module lives, at the interactive interpreter run
>   this:
>
> `import _io`
>
> `_io.__file__`
>
> Under Linux, you should get something like this:
>
> `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so'`
>
> and the equivalent under Windows.

#### In Python 3:

> Note that in Python 3.3, the `_io` module is now **built-in into the 
>   compiler**, so `_io.__file__` no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DLLs folder under your base python install directory if you are on windows.  It contains .pyd modules Ignacio mentions.  I had a similar problem with a portable install.  Including the DLLs folder contents to my install fixed it.  I am using python 2.5.