# What does this error message mean?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

It appears after I did some reconfigruation to my GAE / django project namely using appengine_config.py to select django 1.2 Does this error message mean I'm running the wrong version of python? If so, which version should I be running? I previously used to latest available preinstalled python version at ubuntu 11.

```
--> --> -->

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4113, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4022, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 596, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3095, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2999, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2862, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "/media/Lexar/project/myproject/i18n.py", line 12, in <module>
    from main import Ad
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2478, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2350, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2293, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/myproject/main.py", line 1573, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2478, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2350, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2293, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 10, in <module>
    import io
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2478, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2350, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1513, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/project/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2293, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Comment: Basically, "No module named _io". I think this will answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003276/python-import-io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **python 2.7**

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
```

The Python runtime environment uses **Python 2.5.2**